# Microsoft Defender onboarding Issues for MAC

Tags: endpoint, microsoft365-defender

Has anyone ever ran into this issue when you try to onboard your MAC with Microsoft Defender:

Generating /Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Defender/com.microsoft.wdav.atp.plist
/Users/willhardison/Documents/Defender/MicrosoftDefenderATPOnboardingMacOs.sh: line 37: /Library/Application Support/Microsoft/Defender/com.microsoft.wdav.atp.plist: Operation not permitted

That it would permit me to onboard the package

Answer (score 0):

Try running this command before launching the script:

```
sudo mdatp config tamper-protection enforcement-level --value Disabled
```

Then run the script:

```
sudo bash MicrosoftDefenderATPOnboardingMacOS.sh
```

Enable the tamper protection:

```
sudo mdatp config tamper-protection enforcement-level --value Block
```